# if <input> box has value, then display a <div> in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

i have 2 input box `id` and `name` if this input box is empty, it will not display `div#content`.

i also have an event where, if the user typed-in his `id` and hit button `onclick` it will fetch the associated name of that `id`.

- the condition to fetch the data via ajax and print the result in the  `<input>` field is working.
- the condition to check if both `<input>`has a value before displaying
  `div#content` is also working.

the part where im struggling is, if i typed-in the `id` number, clicked the `<button>`, the result from the ajax will insert the value in my **name** `<input>` field, even though all `<input>` (id & name) has values, the `div#content` still wont appear.

but if i type manually, without using the button, `div#content` appears.

this `<input>` html markup below, with a class name of `required`.

```
<input name="id" id="id" class="required" type="text" placeholder="ID"> 
<button id="myButton">

<input name="name" id="name" class="required" type="text" placeholder="Name">
```

this is my JS. which checks if my `<input class="required">` has a value. if none, nothing happens. if true, it will display a div `#content`.

```
$('.required').on("keyup keypress change", function () { 
var flag = true;

$('.required').each(function() {
if ($(this).val() == "") {    //if value of <input> is empty
   flag = false;
});

if (flag) {
   $("#content").slideDown("slow");
   $("#content").show();
}
```

simultaneously, i also have a script that fetches the associated `name` based on the `ID` input.

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function () {  //on click of button
var id = $j('#id').val();  //get the value of input id

$.getJSON(....) {   // send this to ajax.php to retrieve the associated name
   $.each(.......) {    //fetch it via json_encode
   var name = data[key]["name"];   //store in a var name
   $("#name").val(name);     // insert the value in the <input> 
});
});
```

[edit]

yes, thanks for the typo. but that wasnt the problem.

if i try each of the code (standalone)

- check if all input field has value then display content = okay
- fetch data via ajax and display result in input = okay

but if i try to make them both work together, the div#content doesnt display at all. even though all the fields has values.

Comment: Typo `$("#content").slideDown("slow);` change it to `$("#content").slideDown("slow");`  missing quotes .

Comment: Sounds like you are missing a `$('div#content').show();`

Comment: is there are a reason for not simply showing the `div#content` from inside the click handler when there is valid data being returned?